# Normalizr: Is it best practice to filter out data that client is not consuming by using Entity.processStrategy method?

Tags: javascript, json, redux, normalizr

I'm using Redux to manage state and I want to store exactly the data that the client consumes. Nothing more.

Let's say that the server responds (JSON) with a list of Users and each user contains 20 properties (id, name, age, gender, nationality, etc.).

But, the client only consumes 3 of them (id, name, nationality).

Is it considered best practice to use Entity.processStrategy method in order to filter out unused properties? The normalizr [docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#entitykey-definition---options--) (under processStrategy) mention:

> Note: It is recommended to always return a copy of your input and not
>   modify the original.

If not, are there any suggestions?

Comment: The best practice would be to ask your backend to only send the fields you need :) Check if it supports some sort of a projection mechanism.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko  What if I don't have access to the back end and a projection mechanism is not supported? :)